# Merging two strings in Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, thumb

I'm trying to merge two simple strings in assembly, in a basic fashion, eg:

String 1: AAAAAA

String 2: BBB

Result: ABABABAAA

So just alternating characters.

I've been trying to do this for a bit, but for some reason, I never reach the null terminators on my strings, and the debugger is making it impossible for me to even figure out how to find out if the strings are being combined in the first place.

```
        AREA HW42, CODE, READONLY

        ENTRY

        EXPORT main

main
MAX_LEN EQU 100
    LDR R8, =StrOne
    LDR R9, =StrTwo

Loop
    LDRB R3, [R8], #1
    STRB R3, [r2], #1
    LDRB r4, [r9], #1
    STRB r4, [r2], #1
    ORR R5, R3, R4
    CBZ R5, DONE
    B Loop

    LDR R8, =MixStr
    STR R3, [R8]

DONE
stop
        MOV r0, #0x18
        LDR r1, =0x20026
        SVC #0x11

        ALIGN

        AREA HWData, DATA, READWRITE
        EXPORT adrStrOne
        EXPORT adrStrTwo
        EXPORT adrMixStr

StrOne  DCB "HLO",0
StrTwo  DCB "EL",0
MixStr  SPACE MAX_LEN

adrStrOne DCD StrOne
adrStrTwo DCD StrTwo
adrMixStr DCD MixStr
        ALIGN

        END
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try single-stepping with a debugger to see what's in registers?  Although probably re-initializing R8 and R9 to point to the start of your string *inside* the loop is a problem.  (Which you would have easily noticed if you'd used a debugger.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm still trying to- figure out the debugger. I open it up, but i get smacked in the face with a very large amount of very cryptic boxes. For example, single stepping seems to move through the "dissassembly" box, and not my code, and the two are- loosely related somehow. So for now, I'm trying to learn both the language and the tools. I did fix that one error, but I still dont seem to have it working.

Comment: You're writing in asm, so the disassembly is basically the same thing as your source.  It can be nice to have the comments from the source, though.  Anyway, you need to be using a debugger.  Most people consider it essential for developing asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes You say its basically the same thing, but it doesn't even- resemble my code. But that's okay! I'll figure it out. Its just deeply hard to learn to program in a language when you cant even figure out how to view the results at all. For example, lets say I wanted to view the contents of MixStr at the end, to find out if it mixed the strings. I have no idea how to do that, and googling "How to view strings in memory uVision 5" reveals- nothing but pain. Do I really have to learn how to decode a entire memory table to find out what's even stored there?

Comment: IDK, I could tell you how to do it in GDB.  Does your debugger use a different syntax than your source or something?  Remember that you write an asm, but that's just a proxy for the machine code which the CPU actually runs.  There can be multiple syntaxes for the same instructions, but they're really the same instruction.  (Unless something goes wrong and your machine-code bytes are being decoded as thumb instructions when the assembler wrote them as ARM instructions or something...)

Comment: _"it doesn't even resemble my code"_ - are you sure you're debugging from the `main` symbol, not from the entry point (i.e. through all the startup and library code)?

Comment: Use a breakpoint at the top of *your function* to ensure that you're debugging the right code.

Answer (score 1):

```
ORR R5, R3, R4
CBZ R5, DONE
```

This makes it probably keep going until it falls off the end of memory and faults, because your strings are different lengths:

```
'H' | 'E' != 0
'L' | 'L' != 0
'O' | '\0' != 0
'\0' | ??? != 0 (probably)
...
```

If you need to handle different-length strings, you need to check for and handle the end of each one individually.

---

In fact, there's no "probably" about it - due to the layout of your data, the first "???" will actually be the beginning of `MixStr`, which is guaranteed to be nonzero on account of being 'H' by this point, and from then on you run away copying the earlier part of the result into itself, until you fall off the end of the data section, or memory, whichever comes first.

Comment: Oh good catch.  I saw that, and for some reason thought it would work.  I think I had it backwards, and was thinking that it would stop if either character was zero.  (Of course, you need `~a | ~b` for that to work, not just an `a & b` that you can do in one insn, because they could have non-intersecting non-zero bit patterns).

Comment: You do want to break out of the interleave loop as soon as either string ends, though.  (Then only copy the tail of the other one.)